# error: attribute 'android:context' not found

Tags: android, android-manifest

> error: attribute 'android:context' not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: attribute 'android:context' not found., sources=[C:\Users\eMotion4\AndroidStudioProjects\BSMAS\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_splashactivity.xml:2], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF9B1F1C"
    android:context=".splashactivity">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bharatsathi"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/bharatsathi"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because you're using incorrect attribute for `context`. You need to use `tools:context` instead of `android:context`. So, update your xml to use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF9B1F1C"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".splashactivity">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bharatsathi"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/bharatsathi"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this worked for me. i was using app:context=".MainActivity" instead of tools:context=".MainActivity" and changing that did the trick. I am also new to android programming with kotlin and i'm following the official docs. Its interesting

Answer (score 0):

Classes are case-sensitive.

```
android:context=".splashactivity"
```

means there should be an `Activity` sub-class named `splashactivity` in your source code root folder. Make sure it is present. This will be a sub-class of `AppCompatActivity` which extends from `Activity`.

Your class will use the layout mentioned in the posted code by calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashactivity);`.

---

Note: In Java/Kotlin the preferred name will be `SplashActivity` according to naming conventions.